# Is it possible to configure the mono default font for menus?

Tags: .net, winforms, fonts, mono, menu

The winforms default font for menus in mono (Ubuntu 10.04) does not support german umlauts. While I can set the font for form content (this.Font), I could not figure out where to configure the menu font. Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

I am now using a ToolStripMenu which uses Parent.Font as Font. Works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to MainMenu, the font comes from SystemFonts.DefaultFont, and is not configurable.  You would have to change it by changing Mono's source code (System.Windows.Forms/Theme.cs, MenuFont property).

If you are referring to MenuStrip, the font is settable using MenuStrip.Font.

Comment: I was referring to MainMenu.
Maybe I should use a MenuStrip instead.

Do you know why the font is hardcoded?

Comment: Mono follows the .Net framework, and the .Net framework provides no mechanism to change it.  Ideally, SystemFonts.DefaultFont should be picking up your system default font and using it.  You might could test what DefaultFont actually is compared to your system font, and file a bug about them not matching.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the font mono uses by default is the system default font.

Comment: Nope, its not. The default system font supports umlauts.